# API to control a NEST camera?

Tags: google-api

I am lost among the Google/NESt thing. looks like NEST-API has been discontinued, is there an alternative already?
Is there an API available as of now to control a NEST camera? for iOS maybe? Python?

Comment: Just incase you weren't aware, they're launching this in 2020 https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/gboudreau/nest-api

I was able to find an unofficial nest api that uses PHP.

https://github.com/yakushevichsv/NestCameras

Here's an example of somebody using the deprecated API. I'm not sure if this would still work, but it's worth a shot.

https://github.com/floydpink/daily-timelapse

Same deal here, maybe you could see if this still works.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this python package to control nest cameras called [Python-Nest](https://github.com/jkoelker/python-nest/) and it seems to be quite updated. Not as much as I like when Im' searching for a package to use, but I think this would be a good choice. It also supports asyncio.

Comment: Nest developer API doesn't support generating new developer API keys, so this not useful anymore.